# HTACCESS Rewrite Rule .*

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

What does this Line do?

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.test.de [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

It redirects all requests (`.*`) to http://www.test.de with a permanent redirect code (301) and doesn't execute more rules after that (L for last).

Comment: Thanks!
All requests even like /products/index.html?id=111? 
so .* stands for all?

Comment: `.*` is a regular expression matching *'0 to unlimited repetitions of any character'*.